# Teams extension thrwoing UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning Error: BotFrameworkAdapter.processActivity(): 501 ERROR

Tags: node.js, botframework, microsoft-teams

I just got started with teams extensions. I modified the code provided by microsoft. My manifest:

```
 ...
"composeExtensions": [
  {
    "botId": "[BOT ID HERE]",
    "canUpdateConfiguration": true,
    "commands": [
      {
        "id": "createTimeDisplay",
        "type": "action",
        "title": "createTimeDisplay",
        "description": "Creates a clock showing the given time in the users timezone.",
        "initialRun": true,
        "fetchTask": true,
        "context": [
          "commandBox",
          "compose",
          "message"
        ],
        "parameters": [
          {
            "name": "param",
            "title": "param",
            "description": ""
          }
        ],
        "taskInfo": {
          "title": "Create a new time display",
          "width": "medium",
          "height": "medium",
          "url": "[SOME NGROK PATH HERE]/newTimeDisplay"
        }
      }
    ]
  } ...
```

This is my index.js:

```js
// Create bot handlers
const botActivityHandler = new BotActivityHandler();
const server = express();
const port = process.env.port || process.env.PORT || 3978;
server.post('/api/messages', (req, res) => {
    console.log("Posted to api/messages/")
    adapter.processActivity(req, res, async (context) => {
        console.log("processing Activity")
        // Process bot activity
        await botActivityHandler.run(context);
    });
});
server.get('/api/messages', (req, res) => {
    console.log("Get to api/messages/")
    
});

server.listen(port, () => 
    console.log(`\Bot/ME service listening at http://localhost:${port}`)
);
console .log("test")
// Listen for incoming requests.
```

And my botActivityHandler:

```js
class BotActivityHandler extends TeamsActivityHandler {
    constructor() {
        super();
    }
    handleTeamsMessagingExtensionSubmitAction(context, action) {    
        switch (action.commandId) {
        case 'createTimeDisplay':
            return createTimeDisplay(context, action);
        default:
            //return createCardCommand(context, action);
            console.log("Here")
            throw new Error('NotImplemented');
        }
    }
    handleTeamsAppBasedLinkQuery(context, query) {
        console.log("look2")
        const attachment = CardFactory.thumbnailCard('Thumbnail Card',
            query.url,
            ['https://raw.githubusercontent.com/microsoft/botframework-sdk/master/icon.png']);
    
        const result = {
            attachmentLayout: 'list',
            type: 'result',
            attachments: [attachment]
        };
    
        const response = {
            composeExtension: result
        };
        return response;
        }
}
function createTimeDisplay(context, action) {
    console.log("LOOK!!")
    console.log(context)
    const heroCard = CardFactory.heroCard("Test", "Me have text");
    const attachment = { contentType: heroCard.contentType, content: heroCard.content, preview: heroCard };
    return {
        composeExtension: {
            type: 'result',
            attachmentLayout: 'list',
            attachments: [
                attachment
            ]
        }
    };
}
module.exports.BotActivityHandler = BotActivityHandler;
```

This code results in this error message in the console as soon as I click on the extension in a chat:

```
test
Bot/ME service listening at http://localhost:3978
Posted to api/messages/
processing Activity
(node:26072) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: BotFrameworkAdapter.processActivity(): 501 ERROR
    at BotFrameworkAdapter.<anonymous> (E:\dev\gitgarden\teamsTestApp\What is that in my timezone\node_modules\botbuilder\lib\botFrameworkAdapter.js:741:27)
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at fulfilled (E:\dev\gitgarden\teamsTestApp\What is that in my timezone\node_modules\botbuilder\lib\botFrameworkAdapter.js:12:58)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
(node:26072) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise 
which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 2)
(node:26072) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero 
exit code.
```

I have no idea what's wrong. Any help/ideas appreciated.

Comment: Could you please try this [sample](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/main/samples/javascript_nodejs/51.teams-messaging-extensions-action)

Comment: @TheGreydiamond did you solve out the error?

Comment: No, I gave up on this project and did something else instead.